# contains function linkedlist

Tags: java, linked-list, overriding, priority-queue

```
public class state implements Comparator<state>{
        Point a;
        Point b;
        private int path_cost=0;
        ...
}

    class Point {
        int x;
        int y;
        ...
    }
```

for above i have:

```
PriorityQueue<state> openNode= new PriorityQueue<state>();
LinkedList<state> closed =new LinkedList<state>();
state currNode;
```

I need to check if the `Point a` of ANY `openNode` or `closed` equals `currNode`'s `Point a`.

I could use `contains` if i had to match the entire object but here i just care about one variabale (Point a) of state class. I want the method to check all the nodes in PriorityQueue and LinkedList.

*addition:*
I am thinking about using Iterator on my priorityQueue and LinkedList. But i am not sure how to read the value of Point a using Iterator.

Comment: You will need to write one. Do you have a question?

Comment: I am not able to think of a method to do the above!

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Looked like I'd misunderstood slightly. It's simpler than I thought.

```
// I've assumed more conventional names
Point currPoint = currNode.getPointA();
for (State openNode : openNodes) {
    if (openNode.getPointA().equals(currPoint)) {
        return true;
    }
}

for (State closedNode : closedNodes) {
    if (closedNode.getPointA().equals(currPoint)) {
        return true;
    }
}
// No matching points
return false;
```

You could potentially use Guava's `Iterables.concat()` method to make this slightly simpler:

```
for (State node : Iterables.concat(closedNodes, openNodes)) {
    if (node.getPointA().equals(currPoint)) {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

If you need to know *which* node has an equal point A, just change it to:

```
for (State node : Iterables.concat(closedNodes, openNodes)) {
    if (node.getPointA().equals(currPoint)) {
        return node;
    }
}
return null;
```

That will only find *one* such node, of course - there may be multiple matches.

Comment: i need to use the `path_cost` variable if `Point a` of currNode has some match. In this case i will lose that connection. I was thinking about using Iterator on my priorityQueue and LinkedList. But i am not sure how to read the value of Point a using Iterator.

Comment: @parin: Well that's changing the question... you originally only wanted to know *whether there was such a node*. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to either provide equals method on `Point a` for `state` class or just use simple iteration  and iterate over both List for comparison. `contains` method does the same.

**If you use any other method it will be time consuming.**

Very odd method is use `Comparator to check equality`

```
 class PointAComparator implements Comparator<State>

{
    Point p = null;
    public PointAComparator(Point a) {
        p = a;
    }
    @Override
    public int compare(State o1, State o2) {
        return (p.x == o1.a.x && p.y == o1.a.y) ? 1
                : (p.x == o2.a.x && p.y == o2.a.y) ? 1 : -1;
    }
}
```

> Above compare method returns 1 for equal else -1 so when you do sorting then each list will have elements at the start which are equal. and then you can check for first element.

Answer (score 0):

i used method overriding on function `equals` for both the object and achieved my result.

```
       class Point {
            int x;
            int y;
            ...

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other){
        if (other == null) return false;
        if (other == this) return true;
        if (!(other instanceof Point))return false;
        Point otherPoint = (Point)other;
        return (this.x==otherPoint.getX() && this.y==otherPoint.getY() )? true : false;
    }

        }



public class state implements Comparator<state>{
            Point a;
            Point b;
            private int path_cost=0;
            ...
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other){
        if (other == null) return false;
        if (other == this) return true;
        if (!(other instanceof state))return false;
        state otherState = (state)other;
        return ((this.a).equals(otherState.a))? true : false;
    }
    }
```